# How exactly does indexing work?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, indexing, index-buffer

From my understanding, indexing or `IBO`s in OpenGL are mainly used to reduce the number of vertices needed to draw for a given geometry. I understand that with an Index Buffer, OpenGL only draws the vertices with the given indexes and skips any other vertices. But doesn't that eliminate the possibility to use texturing? As far as i am aware, if you skip vertices with index buffers, it also skips their vertex attributes? If i have my vertex attributes set like this:

```
attribute vec4 v_Position;
attribute vec2 v_TexCoord;
```

and then use an index buffer and `glDrawElements(...)`, wont that eliminate the usage of texturing, or does `v_Position` get "reused"? if they don't, how can i texture when using an index buffer?

Comment: Indexing lets you pick which vertex to render from an index, as if you had went through the work of specifying that vertex. You can specify a vertex more than once, in which case it just gets rendered again (usually as part of a different primitive).

Comment: but by specifiying that vertex more than once, wont that also specify its texture coordinate more than once? thus make texturing impossible?

Comment: Yes, the texture coordinates will be specified more than once, because it's part of the vertex. No, it doesn't make texturing impossible, because the texture coordinate is interpolated across the primitive (unless you are using flat shading), and you usually reuse vertexes in different primitives.

Comment: oh no, let me rephrase what i meant: do i need to specify vertices multiple times if i want to texture something?

Comment: for a textured cube, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding several key terms.

"Vertex attributes" are the data that defines each individual vertex. While these include texture coordinates, they also include **position**. In fact, at least if you are not using fixed-function, the meaning of vertex attributes is entirely arbitrary; their meaning is defined by how the vertex shader uses and/or forwards them to following shader stages.

As such, *there is no difference between how position, texture coordinates, and any other vertex attribute are forwarded to the vertex shader.* They are all parsed exactly the same no matter how indexes are used (or not used).

An example vertex shader:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 uvAttr;

out vec2 uv;

void main( )
{
    uv = uvAttr;
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

And the beginning of the fragment shader to which the above is paired:

```
in vec2 uv;
```

The output of vertex shaders is, as you can see, based on the vertex attributes. That output is then interpolated across the faces generated by primitive assembly, before sending it to fragment shaders. Primitive assembly is the main place where indexes come into play: indexes determine how the vertex shader output is used to create actual geometry. That geometry is then broken up into fragments, which are what actually affect the rendering output. Outputs from the vertex shader become inputs to the fragment shader.

After the vertex shader, the vertex attributes cease being defined. Only if you forward them, as above, can they be accessed for use in something like texturing. So, you are not even using the vertex attribute itself as a texture coordinate in the first place: you're using a variable output by the vertex shader and interpolated in primitive assembly/rasterization.

*"if you skip vertices with index buffers, it also skips their vertex attributes"*

Yes - it totally *ignores* the vertex: texture coordinates, position, and whatever else you have defined for that vertex. But only the skipped vertex. The rest continue to be processed normally as if the skipped vertex never existed.

For example. Let us say for the sake of argument I have 5 vertexes. I have these ordered into a bow-tie shape as you can see below. Each vertex has position (a 2 component vector of just x and y) and a single component "brightness" to be used as a color. The center vertex of the bow tie is only defined once, but referenced via indexes twice.

[image: Example 1]

The vertex attributes are:

1. [(1, 1), 0.5], aka [(x, y), brightness]
2. [(1, 5), 0.5]
3. [(3, 3), 0.0]
4. [(5, 5), 0.5]
5. [(5, 1), 0.5]

The indexes are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3.

Note that in this example, the "brightness" might as well stand in for your UV(W) coordinates. It would be interpolated similarly, just as a vector. As I said before, the meaning of vertex attributes is arbitrary.

Now, since you're asking about skipping vertexes, here is what the output would be if I changed the indexes to 1, 2, 4:

[image: Example 2]

And this would be 1, 2, 3:

[image: Example 3]

See the pattern here? OpenGL is concerned with the vertexes that makes up the faces it generates, nothing else. Indexes merely change how those faces are assembled (and can enable it to skip unneeded vertexes being calculated entirely). They have no impact on the meaning of the vertexes that are used and do go into the faces. If the black vertex #3 is skipped, it does not contribute to any face, because it is not *part* of any face.

As an aside, the standard allows implementations to re-use vertex shader output within single draw calls. So, you should expect that using the same index repeatedly will *probably not* result in additional vertex shader calls. I say "probably not" because what your driver actually does is always going to be voodoo.

Note that in this I have intentionally ignored tesselation and geometry shaders. Those are a topic beyond the scope of this question, but can have some interesting implications for how vertex attributes are handled. I also ignored the fact that the ordering of vertexes can be accessed to a degree in shaders, and thus might impact output.

Comment: Thanks for this very thorough answer :) So it skips the vertex completely, ok. Now that would mean, if i wanted to draw a textured dice with different textures on each side, that i couldnt use index buffers to increase performance, because texture coordinates are being skipped, and as such, the cube wouldnt be textured correctly?

Comment: @calcyss That's not what I said. If you skip the vertex, that vertex's texture coordinates are ignored. All others are used as normal. Of course, how you assemble the vertexes (ordering + draw op) can impact how those same vertex attributes end up influencing the output, as shown in my examples. But using indexes does not make texture coordinates go away. It just changes which vertexes out of the ones you provide contribute to the output. Vertexes only contribute to the primitive they are part of. If the vertex you skipped was never part of a given primitive, skipping it has no influence.

Comment: Perhaps I should make demonstration images with actual opengl output.

Answer (score 2):

Index buffer is used for speed.

With index buffer, vertex cache is used to store recently transformed vertices. During transformation, if vertex pointed by index is already transformed and available in vertex cache, it is reused otherwise, vertex is transformed. Without index buffer, vertex cache cannot be utilized so vertices always get transformed. That is why it is important to order your indices to maximize vertex cache hits.

Index buffer is also used for reducing memory footprint.

Single vertex data is usually quite large. For example: to store single precision floating point of position data (x, y, z) requires 12 bytes (assuming that each float requires 4 bytes). This memory requirement gets bigger if you include vertex color, texture coordinate or vertex normal.

If you have a quad composed of two triangles with each vertex consist of position data only (x, y, z). Without index buffer, you require 6 vertices (72 bytes) to store a quad. With 16-bit index buffer, you only need 4 vertices (48 bytes)+ 6 indices (6*2 bytes = 12 bytes) = 60 bytes to store a quad. With index buffer, this memory requirement gets smaller if you have many shared vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm accepting Williams, since it's a little more complete :)